# Cannot get SURF example in EMGU.CV to work?

Tags: emgucv

I am trying to detect a pattern shown in two images. Hence I have been trying to use the SURF algorithim found in emgu.CV, but the "SURFFeature" example that is given gives me the following error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Additional information: OpenCV: norm == NORM_L1 || norm == NORM_L2 || norm == NORM_HAMMING
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

When I try the "Hello World" example and the face detection example, both seem to work fine.

Thanks for any advice!

Fouad.

PS: Emgu.CV can be downloaded from here: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the build was messed up.

http://www.emgu.com/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=74

> Aha, found it.  The error here is in Emgu.Cv.Gpu/GpuBruteForceMatcher.cs lines 22 and 27.
>
> Line 22 currently reads:
>    L2Dist,
>
> It should read:   L2Dist = 4,
>
> Line 27 currently reads:   HammingDist
>
> It should read:   HammingDist = 6

Rebuild the Emgu.CV.Gpu dll with those changes and it works.