# OpenCV (emgu) don't detect the good form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to learn OCR processing. I have decided to create a .net project which use EmguCv wrapper to use OpenCV library.

I have wrote a little piece of code (most of lines come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406958/emgu-finding-image-a-in-image-b)) :

```
    public static Image<Bgr, byte> FindImage(string Imgtemplate, string Imgsource, float coeff)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> source = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Imgsource); // Image B
        Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Imgtemplate); // Image A
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageToShow = source.Copy();

        using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
        {
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            //double minValues = 0, maxValues = 0;
            Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
            //Point minLocations = new Point(), maxLocations = new Point();
            //CvInvoke.Normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.NormType.MinMax, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Default, new Mat());
            //CvInvoke.MinMaxLoc(result, ref minValues, ref maxValues, ref minLocations, ref maxLocations, new Mat());
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);

            // You can try different values of the threshold. I guess somewhere between 0.75 and 0.95 would be good.
            if (maxValues[0] > coeff)
            {
                // This is a match. Do something with it, for example draw a rectangle around it.
                Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], template.Size);
                //Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations, template.Size);
                imageToShow.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Green), 1);
            }
        }

        // Show imageToShow in an ImageBox (here assumed to be called imageBox1)
        //imageBox1.Image = imageToShow;
        return imageToShow;

    }
```

The source image is :

[image]

The template image is :

[image]

Both images are jpg. The result (with 100 % match) of the method is :

[image]

As you can see the result isn't the good one :/. However, when i run my method with the example given on OpenCV site I have a good result (67 % match) :

[image]

Anyone have an idea about my problem ?
For the OpenCV example result is there any way to improve the matches percent ? Which option/parameter is the best ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The template **need** to be extracted from the source image.